# TinyMCE in customizer

Tags: tinymce, theme-customizer

I use TinyMce on my customizer (for obv reasons). 
But i encounter a problem that i do not seem to have the answer to.
Let me first share you my code that are crucial:

**Functions.php**

```
// text editor

if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Customize_Control' ) )
    return NULL;
/**
 * Class to create a custom tags control
 */
class Text_Editor_Custom_Control extends WP_Customize_Control
{
    /**
     * Render the content on the theme customizer page
     */
    public function render_content()
    {
        ?>
        <label>
            <span class="customize-text_editor"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
            <input class="wp-editor-area" type="hidden" <?php $this->link(); ?> value="<?php echo esc_textarea( $this->value() ); ?>">
            <?php
            $settings = array(
                'textarea_name' => $this->id,
                'media_buttons' => false,
                'drag_drop_upload' => false,
                'teeny' => true,
                'quicktags' => false,
                'textarea_rows' => 5,
            );
            $this->filter_editor_setting_link();
            wp_editor($this->value(), $this->id, $settings );
            ?>
        </label>
        <?php
        do_action('admin_footer');
        do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
    }
    private function filter_editor_setting_link() {
        add_filter( 'the_editor', function( $output ) { return preg_replace( '/<textarea/', '<textarea ' . $this->get_link(), $output, 1 ); } );
    }
}

function editor_customizer_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-editor-customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/customizer.js', array( 'jquery' ), rand(), true );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'editor_customizer_script' );
```

**Customizer.php**

```
    // content 1 text

$wp_customize->add_setting('home_content1_text', array(
    'default' => 'Here goes an awesome title!',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
));
$wp_customize->add_control(new Text_Editor_Custom_Control( $wp_customize, 'home_content1_text', array(
    'label' => __('Text content 1', 'DesignitMultistore'),
    'section' => 'home_content_1',
    'description' => __('Here you can add a title for your content', 'DesignitMultistore'),
    'priority' => 5,
)));

    //slider text 1 control
$wp_customize->add_setting('slider_text_1', array(
    'default' => _x('Welcome to the Designit Multistore theme for Wordpress', 'DesignitMultistore'),
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
));
$wp_customize->add_control(new Text_Editor_Custom_Control( $wp_customize, 'slider_text_1', array(
    'description' => __('The text for first image for the slider', 'DesignitMultistore'),
    'label' => __('Slider Text 1', 'DesignitMultistore'),
    'section' => 'Designit_slider_slide1',
    'priority' => 3,
)));
```

**Customizer.JS**

```
    ( function( $ ) {
    wp.customizerCtrlEditor = {

        init: function() {

            $(window).load(function(){
                var adjustArea = $('textarea.wp-editor-area');
                adjustArea.each(function(){
                    var tArea = $(this),
                        id = tArea.attr('id'),
                        input = $('input[data-customize-setting-link="'+ id +'"]'),
                        editor = tinyMCE.get(id),
                        setChange,
                        content;

                    if(editor){
                        editor.onChange.add(function (ed, e) {
                            ed.save();
                            content = editor.getContent();
                            clearTimeout(setChange);
                            setChange = setTimeout(function(){
                                input.val(content).trigger('change');
                            },500);
                        });
                    }

                    if(editor){
                        editor.onChange.add(function (ed, e) {
                            ed.save();
                            content = editor.getContent();
                            clearTimeout(setChange);
                            setChange = setTimeout(function(){
                                input.val(content).trigger('change');
                            },500);
                        });
                    }

                    tArea.css({
                        visibility: 'visible'
                    }).on('keyup', function(){
                        content = tArea.val();
                        clearTimeout(setChange);
                        setChange = setTimeout(function(){
                            input.val(content).trigger('change');
                        },500);
                    });
                });
            });
        }

    };

    wp.customizerCtrlEditor.init();

} )( jQuery );
```

**Now the problem**

Everything seems to work fine. I do have an TinyMce editor.
Its not registering that something has been changed. And when i change something else and save it along with the changes is not saved either.

Does someone have a working example of a RTE or TinyMce editor that replaces the textarea's on the customizer?

**Update**

Only the last instance that i define in my customizer.php works. By now i have 14 textarea's. The text area works fine on the 14th but not on 1-13th

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that for each area that remains he creates that number of tinymce's within that area. So the first area has 14 tinymce's overlapping eachother. The second 13 ; the thirth 14 etc etc. Until the last has only 1 and therefor working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem has been "solved" by doing the following :

The problem is that do_action is getting called each time that i have a new class. But it needs to be called only in the last. Otherwise this creates a bunch of admin_print_footer_scripts.

Since i'm writing the code myself and i don't intend on selling this for now i can just count the number of new class instances i create. Which is 14 at this point.

So i altered it like this :

**Functions.php**

```
class Text_Editor_Custom_Control extends WP_Customize_Control
{

    /**
     * Render the content on the theme customizer page
     */
    public function render_content()
    {
        static $i = 1;
        ?>
        <label>
            <span class="customize-text_editor"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
            <input class="wp-editor-area" type="hidden" <?php $this->link(); ?> value="<?php echo esc_textarea( $this->value() ); ?>">
            <?php
            $content = $this->value();
            $editor_id = $this->id;
            $settings = array(
                'textarea_name' => $this->id,
                'media_buttons' => false,
                'drag_drop_upload' => false,
                'teeny' => true,
                'quicktags' => false,
                'textarea_rows' => 5,
            );
            wp_editor($content, $editor_id, $settings );


            if( $i == 14) {
                do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
            }
            $i++;

            ?>
        </label>
        <?php
    }
};

function editor_customizer_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-editor-customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/customizer.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'editor_customizer_script' );
```

If someone knows how i can count the times i call that new class in my customizer and use it in my functions.php to know when the last time its called i can call the do_action... It would help a lot

Comment: Btw , i still find it very stupid that i don't get my bounty back. Got no help for selling my reputation and i spend hours on figuring this out on my own. Last time i will use the bounty system. I putted this answer up to help other ppl in the future hopefulle

Comment: Just throwing this out there - the [Kirki plugin/library](https://github.com/aristath/kirki) does support multiple editors in the customizer, so you could check out its code for ideas to use with your implementation.

Comment: Thanks , i will sure take a look at their code when i have the time to study their library!

Answer (score 3):

SwAt.Be, your own answer helped me a bunch and I've nailed the problem of printing admin scripts after the last rendition of wp_editor. Also see how I pass JS setup function as tinymce option to sync the editor changes with WP customizer to make it work properly.

```php
if (class_exists('WP_Customize_Control')) {
  class WP_Customize_Teeny_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
    function __construct($manager, $id, $options) {
      parent::__construct($manager, $id, $options);

      global $num_customizer_teenies_initiated;
      $num_customizer_teenies_initiated = empty($num_customizer_teenies_initiated)
        ? 1
        : $num_customizer_teenies_initiated + 1;
    }
    function render_content() {
      global $num_customizer_teenies_initiated, $num_customizer_teenies_rendered;
      $num_customizer_teenies_rendered = empty($num_customizer_teenies_rendered)
        ? 1
        : $num_customizer_teenies_rendered + 1;

      $value = $this->value();
      ?>
        <label>
          <span class="customize-text_editor"><?php echo esc_html($this->label); ?></span>
          <input id="<?php echo $this->id ?>-link" class="wp-editor-area" type="hidden" <?php $this->link(); ?> value="<?php echo esc_textarea($value); ?>">
          <?php
            wp_editor($value, $this->id, [
              'textarea_name' => $this->id,
              'media_buttons' => false,
              'drag_drop_upload' => false,
              'teeny' => true,
              'quicktags' => false,
              'textarea_rows' => 5,
              // MAKE SURE TINYMCE CHANGES ARE LINKED TO CUSTOMIZER
              'tinymce' => [
                'setup' => "function (editor) {
                  var cb = function () {
                    var linkInput = document.getElementById('$this->id-link')
                    linkInput.value = editor.getContent()
                    linkInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
                  }
                  editor.on('Change', cb)
                  editor.on('Undo', cb)
                  editor.on('Redo', cb)
                  editor.on('KeyUp', cb) // Remove this if it seems like an overkill
                }"
              ]
            ]);
          ?>
        </label>
      <?php
      // PRINT THEM ADMIN SCRIPTS AFTER LAST EDITOR
      if ($num_customizer_teenies_rendered == $num_customizer_teenies_initiated)
        do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
    }
  }
}

// TRY IT
add_action('customize_register', function ($wp_customize) {
  $wp_customize->add_section('footer_section' , [
    'title' => __('Footer', 'musiccase'),
    'priority' => 100
  ]);

  // 1st EDITOR
  $wp_customize->add_setting('footer_contact', [
    'type' => 'option'
  ]);
  $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Teeny_Control($wp_customize, 'footer_contact', [
    'label' => __('Contact Info', 'musiccase'),
    'section' => 'footer_section'
  ]));

  // 2nd EDITOR
  $wp_customize->add_setting('footer_contact_2', [
    'type' => 'option'
  ]);
  $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Teeny_Control($wp_customize, 'footer_contact_2', [
    'label' => __('Contact Info 2', 'musiccase'),
    'section' => 'footer_section'
  ]));
}, 20);
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach that is for sure. I will test it out myself since i'm using this tiny mce editor in every theme that i create and every website that i develop.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm a bit too late for the answer, but as far as the count you could use this:  (add the counter and __construct() to the top of your class for actual use)  NOT tested but should be good to go.

```
<?php
class Text_Editor_Custom_Control {
    public static $counter = 0;

    function __construct() {
        self::$counter++;
        self::$lastcall= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}

new Text_Editor_Custom_Control();
new Text_Editor_Custom_Control();
new Text_Editor_Custom_Control();

echo Text_Editor_Custom_Control::$counter;  //would be 3

echo Text_Editor_Custom_Control::$counter;  //shows datetime of last call
?>
```

Comment: No time to test it out but i will give you the bounty since you took the time to answer. Will comment later if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies inside `customizer.js` where you try to select the `.wp-editor-area`. However the `input[data-customize-setting-link="'+ id +'"]` does not select this input because the `id` returns the `control` instead of the `setting`.

**To fix this**

give the input `.wp-editor-area` an id `id="tinymce-input"`

and use it to select this input in your `customizer.js` by changing `input = $('input[data-customize-setting-link="'+ id +'"]')` into `input = $('#tinymce-input')`